# How to change default permissions for files inside a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created a directory named myscripts.I want each file created inside this directory to have executable permission. How to do that?

Comment: The default permissions come from the umask and are not related to a directory, and even those don't affect the x-bit of a regular file. You did not specify how you create the files. If you use a script, this script could of course set the x-bit. I am not aware of a text editor which would offer to automatically set the x-bit for a file having a `#!`  line, but this would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "chmod +x -R foldername/"

Answer (score -2):

Use command chmod with * that will delete all files in directory at once 
Chmod 777 *

Comment: Oh, that may not be what you want. That leaves all files world-readable, writable and executable. Perhaps you intended `chmod -R 0755 dir/*` for user, group and world executable, or  `chmod -R 0750 dir/*` for user and group executable.